# Wrong sort order in favorites tab on global profile

Tags: bug, bookmarks, sorting, network-profile

The [global favorites list](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=favorites) is by default sorted by votes. On [my list](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=favorites), everything is sorted correctly except for a [single question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/110286/64458) (which, coincidentally or not, is my own):

[image]

It's not likely to be a caching problem, the last upvote on that question is from [December 2017](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/110286/timeline). The question above it has been locked since 2014 and didn't receive any votes for a long time.

Comment: Most likely undo of a vote, which was not synchronized with the network profile. I'm pretty sure that when a new vote will be cast (on the question with 52 votes), it will be fixed in few minutes, as it will kick the network profile caching and synchronize the data.

Comment: If you want to test Shadow's hypothesis you could upvote and retract to try to force a synchronisation.

Comment: @ShadowWizard one of the 51 questions has been voted up to 52, but it's still under the locked 51 post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcQsh.png