# How do I see all my bookmarks without looking through every community?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Here's my scenario: about a year ago, I remember bookmarking a question that I would want to return to if I ever formatted my hard drive. That day came, but it took me a lot of time to find the bookmark because I had to click on every community, look at my profile, look at my bookmarks, and see if what I was looking for was mentioned there.

Is there a way I can see all my bookmarks at once, regardless of which community they are on? It would save me a lot of time in situations like this.

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=bookmarks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I see a list of questions that I have favourited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339109/can-i-see-a-list-of-questions-that-i-have-favourited). The answer links to the network profile bookmarks tab. Also linked here: [What's the difference between “bookmarking” and “following” a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/345785/289905), [Wrong sort order in favorites tab on global profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307574/289905), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320820/289905).

Comment: Also, the **inbookmarks** search operator can be used to search within your favorite/bookmark list for text/time/etc.